# Curl - different result in node (child process) and terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, http, curl

So I accidentally found something weird and can't figure out why is it.

I make this curl in my terminal (which is ZSH on iTerm):

```
curl -I https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find\?text\=1%20TX%2077979\&f\=json
```

And the response is:

```
HTTP/2 200
date: Wed, 28 Oct 2020 17:31:12 GMT
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 374
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
server:
etag: dc0a3f17
x-esri-ftiles-cache-compress: true
cache-control: max-age=300
x-cached: MISS
vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
```

But if I run the same curl as exec child_process in node (v14.14.0) like this:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const url = 'https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find\?text\=1%20TX%2077979\&f\=json';

return exec(`curl -I ${url}`, (err, std) => {
  console.log(std);
});
```

The response look like this:

```
HTTP/2 403 
date: Wed, 28 Oct 2020 17:17:18 GMT
content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
content-length: 680
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
server:
```

Can anyone explain it to me?

----- EDIT -----

To andrew:
I was using urls that contains '&' but they ended with '&query=' which is not obligatory and it still returned HTTP 200 and other needed info, that's why I didn't even notice.

Comment: As you found, you need to quote the URL if it contains `&` character since this will be interpreted by the shell as a control operator. Do you have any example URL's with `&` that did not do this? If `&` appears anywhere in your command or arguments and is not quoted or escaped `\&` I think you'd run into the same issue all the time.

Comment: @drew010 you're right. I have urls that contains '&' but they end with '&query=' which is not obligatory and it still returns HTTP 200 and other needed info, that's why I didn't even notice. Thanks.

Comment: That makes sense! Sometimes the & doesn't make the command fail completely and can make it harder to track down issues, like part of the URL being truncated but still working to a degree.

Answer (score 1):

As @drew010 wrote:

> As you found, you need to quote the URL if it contains & character
> since this will be interpreted by the shell as a control operator. If
> & appears anywhere in your command or arguments and is not quoted or
> escaped & I think you'd run into the same issue all the time.

Ok, so according to a documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

> The command string passed to the exec function is processed directly
> by the shell and special characters (vary based on shell) need to be
> dealt with accordingly:

So after performing 'echo' the same way I found out that end of url ("&f=json") is being removed.

After adding quotes around url variable interpolation it works fine.

```
exec(`curl -I "${url}"`, (err, std) =>
```

My initial confusion **"why is it different when it should do the same"** was also part of my believe that 'exec' would just pass it to the terminal I'm using, which as I mentioned before is iTerm with ZSH, because it is set as default terminal on my OS. That assumption was wrong and it is mentioned in the documentation:

> shell Shell to execute the command with. See Shell requirements and
> Default Windows shell. Default: '/bin/sh' on Unix

So **it is not using default OS terminal, but just sh.** But it is possible to use whichever you want with 'shell' option.